# Set tabstop to false for an entire Access form?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

When using a splitform datasheet,it this can become frustrating when the splitform datasheet jumps to the column which gets selected in the form.

Setting `TabStop` to false mostly fixes this problem.

But I have to change this for each form and even if I programmatically do it I still have to remember to do this, etc.

- Is there any way to set the default `TabStop` field for an entire Access form to false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is create a "template" form for my project.  This template includes my desired default settings as well as some code snippets and other graphical elements.  Then, instead of adding a new form, I make a copy of my template as save it as the new form.  Saves me the time of having to set properties I always have set.  I typically have one template for main forms and one for sub-forms that are datasheets.